# Microsoft access tables based on given Query

Tags: ms-access

Microsoft access:-Is there any way to find all tables/forms/reports associated with given Query?

I am able to get all the queries associated with a table. Now I want to search all the tables, forms, reports etc associated with a particular query I have in the database.

Received this database for maintenance.

Comment: This database is ver. 2003

Comment: Nuts!  I was thinking about Access' "Track name Autocorrect info" option, but I can't remember how to find it it Access 2003.  If you can find it, set it, wait for Access to gather its object dependency data, close and reopen the database ... then find where to select a query and then view its dependency info ... "objects which depend on me".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rick Fisher's 'Find and Replace'](http://www.rickworld.com/products.html)